# What is the Sprite Kit equivalent to a Box2D sensor body?

Tags: box2d, sprite-kit

I need to simulate a fan. In Box2D, I do this through the use of a sensor body. I haven't discovered anything in SK that works similarly. I could be wrong. Any suggestions? thanks a lot!

Comment: What kind of fan? A ceiling fan? A triangle fan?

Answer (score 3):

If what you're trying to do is create a body that will result in contact notifications but not collisions, you can use the `categoryBitMask`, `collisionBitMask`, and `contactTestBitMask` properties:

Select a bit to represent the sensor category:

```
#define kSensorCategoryBit (0)                         // Pick your own bit here
#define kSensorCategory    (1 << (kSensorCategoryBit))
```

Set the properties for the sensor body:

```
sensorBody.categoryBitMask    = kSensorCategory; // Set sensor category bit
sensorBody.collisionBitMask   = 0x00000000;      // Prevent all collisions
sensorBody.contactTestBitMask = 0x00000000;      // Prevent contacts between sensors
```

Set the properties for the other bodies that you want notifications for:

```
otherBody.contactTestBitMask |= kSensorCategory; // Set sensor category bit
```

Set the physics world's contact delegate:

```
scene.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = contactDelegate;
```

Implement the contact delegate methods for the `contactDelegate` object:

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
- (void)didEndContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
```

See Apple's documentation on [`SKPhysicsContact`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsContactDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/SKPhysicsContactDelegate) for more information. Hope that helps...

Comment: good point! I never really understood why Box2D needed a separate flag for "sensor" bodies when you could do the same with contact categories.